# Time of clock is not updating in c++

Tags: c++, date, time

```
#include <ctime>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



int main() {

    time_t t = time(0);   // get time now

    struct tm * now = localtime( & t );

    cout <<  now->tm_mday << '-'//day

         << (now->tm_mon +1 )  << '-'//month

         << (now->tm_year +1900 )//year

         <<endl

         <<now->tm_hour//hour

         <<'-'<<now->tm_min//min

         <<'-'<< now->tm_sec//sec

         << endl;



         return 0;

}
```

This piece of code gives me the system date and time,the only problem i have is that the time is not updating.

For example:= the time is not moving forward and is stuck at a fixed time like 1.33.10

Comment: Please edit your question to indent your code better. On which hardware, on which operating system, with which compiler and compilation options, are you running that? Are you aware of [strftime(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) & [`<chrono>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) ? Did you compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`)? Did you **use the debugger** (`gdb`)?

Comment: You are probably lacking some `#include` directive. [time(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/time.2.html) documents that you need `#include <time.h>`

Comment: This works fine for me (after fixing braces).

Comment: i edited the code and i am aware of strftime and <chrono> but i guess none of them will help me updating the time.

Comment: i am using windows 7 with code block compiler.

Comment: Where's the code to update the time? The time isn't updating because -- you have no code to update it.

Comment: to update we just need an infinite loop per second whether its for,while or any other. But my problem was even with infinite loop i was only getting a fixed time and date output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clear the console and display date again every a given amount of time.

Consider following example (compile with `-std=c++11`):

```
#include <iostream>                             // IO
#include <ctime>                                // time
#include <thread>                               // threads
#include <chrono>                               // chrono

int main(){
    while(true){
        system("clear");                        // clear console

        time_t t = time(0);                     // get time now
        struct tm* now = localtime(&t);

        std::cout   <<  now->tm_mday            << '-'          // day
                    << (now->tm_mon + 1)        << '-'          // month
                    << (now->tm_year + 1900)    << std::endl    // year

                    << now->tm_hour             << '-'          // hour
                    << now->tm_min              << '-'          // min
                    << now->tm_sec              << std::endl    // sec
        ;

        // sleep for 1000 ms (=1s)
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In given code, we infinitelly loop the code that:

1. Clears the console
2. Re`cout` the date
3. Waits `1000ms` *(`1s`)*

Comment: In codeblocks, you can enable `c++11` (to use [`<chrono>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/)) by `Settings` > `Compiler Settings` > `Global compiler settings` > `Compiler settings` > `Compiler flags` > check `Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard` > `OK`.

Comment: Loved your work and thank you stackoverflow for quick response.